# Sphinx related table string attribute

Tags: sql, sphinx

Here's an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

Suppose I have a one-to-many relationship between a Cookbook and Recipe, with fields 'id' and 'name' in both tables. Currently, searches return only a "name" field for recipes, so results might look like this -

RECIPES

- result name 1
- result name 2
- result name 3
- ...

What I'd like to see, without making additional database calls or search queries using the sql_attr_uint for the foreignkey, is the following:

RECIPES

- result name 1 ---------- cookbook name for this result
- result name 2 ---------- cookbook name for this result
- result name 3 ---------- cookbook name for this result
- ...

I know of sql_attr_string, but this appears useful only when adding a single arbitrary string to each document. I need something like a sql_joined_field that isn't full-text searchable, but is instead simply stored in the document with the appropriate value from the query.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I stumbled upon the solution, having been a bit confused by the Sphinx documentation:

> All of the columns that are neither document ID (the first one) nor attributes will be full-text indexed.

I took this to mean that no matter what, fields I placed in the sql_query would be full-text indexed. In fact, specifying a field as an "attribute" changes this behavior, in effect removing the full-text indexing of the field and instead just placing it in the document.

To solve my problem, I simply wrote my JOIN in the main sql_query (since sql_joined_field doesn't appear to allow one to specify it as an attribute) and set the field as sql_attr_string.

Answer (score 0):

An option to deal with one-to-many string attributes is to use some MySQL tricks to pull the textual columns into the `sql_query`.  For example;

> SELECT DISTINCT *, GROUP_CONCAT(tm.text_field SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table t INNER JOIN table_many tm ON t.id = tm.t_id;

It can also work as an additional subquery, which may be more convenient if you have a more complex set of joins.

> SELECT *,
>   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text_field SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table_many tm WHERE t.id = tm.t_id)
>   FROM table t